# How do I update a label with information that changes based on a button click

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()

class Person:
    def __init__ (self):

        self.health = 100

    def sword(self): 
        self.health = self.health - 10
        print(self.health)

n = Person()

sh = tkinter.Label(top, text=str(n.health)).place(x = .5,
                                          y = .5)

button = tkinter.Button(top, text="sword", command=n.sword)
button.place(relx=0.015, rely=0.5, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)
                        

top.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make a mini app that whenever I click the "sword" button it takes away 10 health and displays how much you have left on the screen.